# Find information in a table

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a thead and couple of tr in a tbody

When I click on a cell in a tr, i want to traverse to the text of the cell that is before it

For eg if i clicked on Cell 3 of Row 3, i want to find the text of Cell2 of Row 3

How i do it?

Edit: I cancelled my edit. I will open a new question to avoid confusiing user who helping me.

Comment: What happens if you click on Cell 1 Row 3? Is Cell 3 Row 2 (supposing we have 3 Cells per row) to be returned then?

Comment: thanks i want to find in the same row..not different one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
$("td").click(function(){
  text = $(this).prev("td").text();
  alert(text);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("td.my_class").click(function() {
    var previous_sibling = $(this).prev();
    // Do something
});
```